# How to add dependency to package.json later

Tags: node.js

In my application I have installed few node modules using below command

```
 npm install <modulename>
```

I forgot to mention "--save" to save the dependency list to package.json file.

Now I would like to update those dependencies in package.json file without updating the file manually  . Any idea how it can be done ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can run the same command again, specifying `--save` flag and it will be automatically included in `package.json`. The only problem is that the version of the package can be updated to newer version, so you may specify the specific version of your app: `npm i --save app@1.0.1`.

Alternatively you can modify `package.json` yourself to include the dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "module": "*"
}
```

Comment: Thanks , doing npm install <modulename> --save  works for me

Comment: what means the`" * "` in your code please, latest version I guess ?

Comment: @J.Doe yep, it get's always the latest version

Comment: More about saving the package as a dependency vs as a dev-dependency is explained in the docs https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

Answer (score 9):

Just do: `npm i name_of_package -S` or the long version: `npm install package_name --save`

If you need to save it as a dev dependency, use the -D flag

Answer (score 1):

If you are here looking for the yarn command instead, use `yarn add`. Examples of npm/yarn alternate commands can be seen in the [installation instructions of material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) where the respective yarn equivalents of the npm commands are stated.

When I used

```
yarn add <modulename>
```

my package.json was automatically updated to contain the new module.